# Google Picker not showing files

Tags: google-api, google-picker

This is my code:

```
var docParent = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
        docsView.setParent(docParent);
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(docsView).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            //setOrigin('http://localhost:61003').
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
```

I'd like to set a default folder that might have "sub-folders" and then pick a file inside of them. 
It was working fine but since a few months it just displays the folders but not the files inside them. So, I've tried to change the addView for a addViewGroup and add FOLDERS and DOCS but it doesn't work either. The folders works always fine, but when i select the sub-folder it says "No items on this folder".

Could you help me please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

i was able to  get Folders and files in one view.Add this view

`addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setParent('root').setIncludeFolders(true))`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the "**no items in this folder**" because you indicated a strictly FOLDER view by using

```
var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
```

Now I'm not sure if Picker API supports the 'view files inside folder' functionality as I haven't found a way to do it. But, using

```
 var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
```

enables you to view all files in your Drive including those that are inside sub-folders.

```
 function createPicker() {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(view).
            setAppId(appId).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! It was working fine until few monthes ago (folders and then files).  I need to set a "root" folder (for example Incomings) and then Select a subfolder (ex: 2017-01) and then the file.The problem I'm having with your solution is that with DOCS will display all files inside the subfolders, and also the subfolders at the same level.

Comment: I could not view my google doc files and came to this answer when googling. I know this is unrelated to the answer, never the less... If you are using `view.setMimeTypes("???");` then be sure that all the drive mime type be sure to set the drive mime types first. I think google starts ignoring mime types after you have input invalid ones.

If you are building the list from valid array of items you might have valid drive mime types later, and that does not work.